# Sum result of Sum of textboxes SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have two different textbox and a total column like:

[image: report design]

That I want to do is to `Sum` all values of Expression of `sJerarquiaNivel5` and `Sum` all values of `sJerarquiaNivel2` then Sum there results and display in total column

I try it using Sum texbox like:

`=Sum(ReportItems!Calculo.Value + ReportItems!Calculo4.Value)`, but it throws an error

[image: error message]

How can I achieve this?

**Update:**

As comments below I try to use `=ReportItems("Calculo").Value + ReportItems("Calculo4").Value`

[image: results]
Problem is report only get last register of sJerarquia and use it instead sum it... It occurs because sJerarquia can have more than one value, I need to sum this value then sum with another sJerarquia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The report items should be referenced like this to sum multiple report items. Using ReportItems in an aggregate function is not allowed.

```
=ReportItems("Calculo").Value + ReportItems("Calculo4").Value
```

I would recommend referencing the actual columns from the query to do the work instead. Something like this. It's a bit easier to maintain.

```
=SUM([Calculo]) + SUM([Calculo4])
```

If sJerarquiaNivel5 and sJerarquiaNivel2 are complex expressions, I'd convert the logic to a SQL CASE statement. Something like this.

```
SELECT 
   sJerarquiaNivel5 = CASE WHEN X = 1 AND Y = 2 THEN Z + 1 END
 , sJerarquiaNivel2 = CASE WHEN X = 3 AND Y = 4 THEN Z + 2 END
FROM 
 your_table_name
```

Comment: Using ReportItems in aggregate function is not allowed.

Comment: Are you still having an issue?

Comment: No, I solve it getting sum in cube with Analysis Services